# List of Features and Limits which can be activated/increased by the support

Tags: apex, visualforce, limits, support, feature-activation

There are a lot of features which can be activated and limits which can be increase if you contact the support. As an examples you can log a case to do the following:

- Activate: Organization Administrators Can Log in as Any User - Summer 12
- Activate: Push Upgrades - Major Versions (for packages with passed Security Review)
- Disable clickjack protection for non-setup Salesforce pages

As far as I know, there is no official documentation of all possible things, which the support can do. So without better knowledge I find myself quite often logging cases and ask for things, which are not possible. E.g.:

- Increase the Mass-Email-Limit for DE form 10 to some higher value. (only possible on trial-EE or test-orgs, not DEs)

My guess: I'm not the only one... This is a waste of time for the support people and for us developers.

Is there any official or inofficial approach of anyone to put together such a list of features and limits the support can change? Even if incomplete, it would help.

I think all of us and the support could be also a benefit if we learn how to **name** the features/limits correctly. I know that there are standing names like that *'Activate: Organization Administrators Can Log in as Any User - Summer 12'* which helps the support to quickly anticipate what you want. Not knowing the proper naming and going with some free text descriptions of what you want instead are error prone and may lead to misunderstandings and unnecessary effort in communication.

Comment: I suggest making any answers for this question Community Wiki so it can be a living document.

Comment: I can look trough all my cases and for sure put some more things in the ring if we can start to build such a list somewhere. All ideas welcome! I like @sfdcfox 's suggestion of a living document.

Comment: How to make answers Community Wiki like @ sfdcfox suggested? I think only @Jagular can do this in his answer himself, right?

Comment: I've started a community wiki that includes all the features I could think of off the top of my head. There's plenty I'm sure I'm missing though.

Comment: See also "What is the Black Tab": http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366/what-is-the-black-tab/471#471

Comment: I've checked off "community wiki" on my answer.  I'm not sure what that does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Limits

Per day limits can be increased temporarily to accommodate unusual business conditions, such as a spam attack, marketing campaigns, etc. All such increased limits can only be increased a certain level without requiring higher authorization (e.g. manager, VP, CEO).

### Rollup summary fields per Object

This increases the number of rollups that can be defined on an object. This has performance penalties associated with it.

### Workflow rules per Object

Increases the number of workflow rules that can fire on an object. This has performance penalties associated with it.

### API calls

Can be increased above the usual limit documented for an org's usual limit. Not useful in retroactive situations, such as a misbehaving app. It is instead used preemptively to load large amounts of data that you know will otherwise disrupt your usual business if API calls were exhausted.

### Mass Emails

Can be increased beyond the usual limit to accommodate an accidental overuse, but usually increased to accommodate marketing campaigns. The limit isn't going to help you send 10,000 mails though (you'd still need a more powerful email platform).

### Web to Lead

Can be increased when an unexpected spike occurs, but often preemptively done to accommodate expected traffic from a campaign.

### Web to Case

Can be increased when an unexpected spike occurs, but often preemptively done to accommodate expected traffic from some situation where many cases might be generated.

## Features

Features that are not commonly used can be enabled by support. Most have no cost, but do permanently alter an organization, and are generally irreversible. It is suggested that features be tested in a Sandbox first.

### Person Accounts

Enables B2C commerce. Affects the way accounts and contacts are shared, and imposes additional limits in reports, etc.

### Multi-Currency

Allows records to support currency, so that reports that cover multiple geographical areas can roll up to a common converted currency. There is some limit to rollup summary fields when using this feature.

### Dated Currency

Provides the additional benefit of allowing exchange rates to have date ranges. Calculations automatically adjust based on the date range and currency exchange.

### Territory Management

Enables additional sharing features, and gives a secondary hierarchy, much like the role hierarchy, so uses can belong to multiple territories, etc.

### Divisions

Provides a "scope" to limit search results, reports, list views, etc in very large organizations so users can effectively navigate data. It does not prevent finding records, it simply makes it more efficient to do so.

### Skinny Tables

Provides a backend table that boosts performance on common, slow queries by aggregating data into a single table. Changes to this table are done by support, and only used on very large data sets where this feature would provide some benefit.

### Delegated Authentication

Allows an organization to define a web service that can be called to authenticate a user's password. Users can no longer reset their password in salesforce.com, but must instead use whatever mechanism is provided by the web service (LDAP, etc).

### Custom Indexes

This provides a custom database index, which can improve query performance in some cases. This is above and beyond the limit of External ID fields you have. There is a performance penalty while saving when using custom indexes.

### Organization Administrators Can Log in as Any User - Summer 12

By default, Users need to allow Admins to login as the user. Having this feature activated lets all admins log in as any user without(!) getting their approval fist, just by clicking on the login link in user list views. This helps Admins to test apps, customizations and settings for different profiles and roles.

Comment: There is a long independent list being maintained at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d0YrpwpeklFfexBxKnyFefZ6EaxQN42uK1PwEz5l0Hc/edit#gid=0. If you were sufficiently motivated it could be merged in here.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of custom report types increased by support.  I'm certain we've done that.

I thought we'd increased the number of rollup summary fields, but the limit is now 10 and we're under that now.  Was this limit lower in the past?

You can call support to have fields on an object made into indices for reporting purposes.  I'm told you can also do this yourself by checking off the "External ID" general option for that field.

It may be possible to get the number of fields per object increased (it has gone up over time anyway).  This happened so far back for us that the person who would have done the increase is no longer here to check with.

Comment: There's no limit on the number of record types.

Comment: I'm referring to custom report types.  I think there used to be limit of 40.