# Increasing field count from 10 in search layout

Tags: global-search

Can I increase the field count from 10 columns to 15 in search layout options. Do I need to contact salesforce support team.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, this is a platform limit (i.e. hard-coded at the system level), not an adjustable control. For a comprehensive list of known support-customizable features, see [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53960/list-of-features-and-limits-which-can-be-activated-increased-by-the-support). Should you find information that contradicts this answer, please update that question's Community Wiki answer; I'll be happy to amend/delete this answer in that situation.